# Can't connect to Visual Studio 2015 SQL DB using Excel?

Tags: sql-server, excel, entity-framework, visual-studio, adodb

[image: Image showing exact same connection details in SQL Server and Excel with one connecting and one not]!

I've tried using ADODB connection string and also in the Excel Data Connection Wizard.

I'm getting this error:

> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen(Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access is denied.

I can see the server created in Visual Studio with its databases fine, no worries, in SQL Server but not connect in Excel. I can connect in Excel to databases created in SQL Server but not those created in VS (2015).

It's seems like a server issue rather than database one but here's the connection string's anyway:

This works fine for database's created in SQL Server:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=DESKTOP-ODUI05F\MSSQL2012;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase
```

but the same string generates the above error when connecting to the server/database created in VS.

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Widly-20160823125202
```

The server name is: `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB`.

The database is generated in VS using EF.

Please help - driving me nuts.

Thank you, Simon

Comment: `LocalDB` is a special, programmer-focused version of SQL Server Express which is **NOT** started up with Windows as a service - it **only** launches either with your application if you run it from within Visual Studio - or if you **manually, explicitly** launch LocalDB using the command-line utility. If neither of those cases is given, then the LocalDB instance **is NOT up** and therefore you cannot connect to it!

Comment: Oh right thanks marc_s. How come it connects alright to (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB in SQL Server then - that must be something different I assume.

having a look now at SqlLocalDB.exe, cheers

Comment: Not quite certain what you mean by run it within VS because when I run the application in there and then try again to connect using Excel Data Connection Wizard it still comes up with the same message.

Comment: See https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-Sf9qx1nwCyQzBCZHNZOE5vbE0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Followed the solution linked below.

Even though it's an MSSQL Server DB you're trying to connect to, using Excel Data Connection Wizard you have to ignore SQL Database connection option and choose "Other/Advanced" instead. I recorded it in a macro which produced all the vital parts for the connection string as follows:

[How to connect to localDB in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/893870/excel-how-to-connect-to-a-sqlserver-localdb/894272)

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11;
Integrated Security=SSPI;
Persist Security Info=False;
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;
Initial Catalog=aspnet-PTL-20160827031609
```

Besides doing the dishes this is my biggest and only achievement today! :)